# SpecFlow test doesn't open repository methods

Tags: repository, specflow

I wrote SpecFlow method, (just add some items in repositories and calculate values after). It worked without mistakes. But now it doesn't.

Made mock of me repositories and filled values them.

I debug it by steps and found, that repositories methods doesn't call. Debuger just ignores and skips it. It isn't joke, I'm sure I made debug point in the right method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was surprise for me, SpecFlow Mock test doesn't call repository method and you can't debug behavior in the method. Mock repository just return value. If you can't get value - that means you added incorrectly data in the repository

Comment: Thank you for coming back and providing an answer on your question. Do not forget to tag it as the solution (when the option becomes available after a day).